# Android Eclipse: Not autocompleting- which editor for a prefernces.xml file

Tags: android, eclipse, editor

I am not sure if its a bug with the latest eclipse, however I am unable to get autocomplete to work with a preferences XML file.  I have tried a few different editors but I can't get any autocomplete to work.

Which editor should I use to optn the file in 
Have tried so far
layout editor, resources editor, xml editors and all it does is beep when i press ctrl space.

Just in case this will help- 
The file is stored under res-->xml-->prefs.xml
and code is currently as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Preference xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
//checkbox should go here


</Preference>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its ok- just worked it out. Here is the answer for others who encounter same issue

I should have put the main tag as being PreferenceScreen - instead of just preferences.
It then correctly opens with the XML Resources Editor which allows you to autocomplete. Silly me!

Here is the working code incase someone else does the same thing. (Also Checkbox is with a capital C!)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<CheckBoxPreference />


</PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 0):

Open eclipse and go to the following:

```
Window > preferences > java > editor > content assist > advanced
```

Select all checkboxes and click ok. After that, restart eclipse.

Comment: Its ok- just worked it out. Here is the answer for others who encounter same issue
 
 
 
I should have put the main tag as being PreferenceScreen - instead of just preferences.
It then correctly opens with the XML Resources Editor which allows you to autocomplete. Silly me!
Here is the working code incase someone else does the same thing. (Also Checkbox is with a capital C!)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<CheckBoxPreference />


</PreferenceScreen>